# How to crop only table from whole Image using OPenCv python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Here is my original Image :-
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipHNK.png)

So from that i need to Crop ony table area and discard all
The expected result is
[Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYX5C.png)

What i done earlier is as follows
1)preprocessed image using erode , dilatation
2)Finded vertical and horizontal line from image using

```
kernel_len = np.array(img).shape[1]//100
ver_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_len))
hor_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_len, 1))
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))
```

3. Later on i finded the counters and finded the boxes

   box = []

   ```
    for c in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        if (w<1000 and h<500):
            image = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            box.append([x,y,w,h])
    plotting = plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
   ```

4)Tryting to cut the maximum area box but it works for few images but not all generic images

***Note :- cv2.boundingRect(counters) logic will not work in my case

Please help me with cropping the image where table is present

Thank You :)

Comment: Try applying threshold before finding contours. You should verify image after every process which would help in applying correct morphological transformations. Also perhaps you would like to change your contour detection condition to detect only the table.

Comment: @Hrushi I did that , Actually i followed almost all blogs from internet but not able to get the table image from original image [https://towardsdatascience.com/a-table-detection-cell-recognition-and-text-extraction-algorithm-to-convert-tables-to-excel-files-902edcf289ec] see link .

Comment: Your link does not work. Please post the image that fails.

Comment: [ https://towardsdatascience.com/a-table-detection-cell-recognition-and-text-extraction-algorithm-to-convert-tables-to-excel-files-902edcf289ec ]    Please check this link